# Python websocket listener

Tags: python, websocket, listener

I am trying to create a python program which will listen to 2 websockets for unlimited time , websockets will be used as one way pipeline and each socket will store data in one variable when new data comes the old data will be replaced.

What will be the best way to do it ? I was looking for Websocket server but i wonder if there is any easier way to just listen to 2 ports/websockets.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a **book**, **tool**, **software library**, **tutorial** or other **off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web.html#websockets coll new lib

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple flask app and use [flask-socketio](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to listen to websockets connections.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to listen to exactly 2 ports like for example 8888 and 8889 the data on ports will be true and false and i should be able to get data to main program ,  so i can do something if both ports are true for example.

Answer (score 0):

A great alternative is the gevent library and gevent-websockets.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent-websocket/

It's pretty strait forward, you can embed any WSGI compliant framework into it, and you can launch several websocket servers with their own processes from the same app.

Best part it's asynchronous (remember to monkey patch).

Answer (score 0):

Using `websockets` and `asyncio` it is easy. Connect two sockets and run listeners on it. Depending on where message handling should happen, either in a forever running coroutine which handles messages on its own or by a higher level handler coroutine which `asyncio.wait`s two listener tasks essentially awaiting `ws.recv()`.

Comment: Can you please provide an example. I am trying to do the same thing and read extensively about `websockets` and about `asyncio` and still can't get it to confidently run in a forever coroutine.